# Changing the 12 hour to 24 hour for the “getHours()” Method

Tags: javascript

hello shows someone how I can add the 24 hour format or would like to remove am and pm need help with please

```html
function formatDateTime(date) {
  var now = new Date();
  var zpad_mins = ':' + (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes();
  if (date.getYear() != now.getYear()) {
    return '' + (1900 + date.getYear());
  } else if ((date.getMonth() != now.getMonth()) ||
             (date.getDate() != now.getDate())) {
    return date.getDate() + ' ' + chrome.i18n.getMessage(
      'month' + date.getMonth() + 'abbr');
  } else if (date.getHours() == 12) {
    return '12' + zpad_mins + 'pm';
  } else if (date.getHours() > 12) {
    return (date.getHours() - 12) + zpad_mins + 'pm';
  }
  return date.getHours() + zpad_mins + 'am';
}
```

Comment: By default it would use the 24H format. So just remove the parts where it goes -12 and appends AM and PM

Comment: now.format("UTC:h:MM:ss TT Z"); you can use the following link to understand http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: thank you for your answers unfortunately i don't have that much experience with .js i will try to implement your suggestions but thank you first

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
         function DisplayCurrentTime(date) {
          var hours = 
           date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
          var minutes = 
           date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes():date.getMinutes();
          var seconds = 
            date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0"+date.getSeconds():date.getSeconds();                              
            var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            return time  
           };

          console.log(DisplayCurrentTime(new Date()))
```